# Reactive data in vue composition api is not rendered in template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I hope I find an answer to why this is not working. I'm trying to fetch data from an api and display it on vue template. Here's my code (summarized).

```
<template>
 <div v-for="song in songs" :key="song.id" class="custom-card" @click="addAudio($event, song)">
  {{ song }}
 </div>
</template>

<script>
const axios = require('axios').default
import { reactive, onMounted } from 'vue'

export default {
        name: 'SongCarousel',
        props: {          
            carouselUrl: String,
        },
        setup(props) {
            let songs = reactive({})
           // const data = localState.value

            onMounted(
                axios
                    .get(props.carouselUrl)
                    .then(response => {
                        songs = response.data.results[0].category_tracks
                        console.log(songs)
                    })
            )

            return {
                songs,
            }
        },
</script>
```

With this code, I can see the fetched 'songs' in the console but it's not rendered in the page. I have tried onBeforeMount, onRenderTriggered, onUpdated but none is working. I can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reactive` should have an object as parameter :

```
<template>
 <div v-for="song in state.songs" :key="song.id" class="custom-card" @click="addAudio($event, song)">
  {{ song }}
 </div>
</template>

<script>
const axios = require('axios').default
import { reactive, onMounted } from 'vue'

export default {
        name: 'SongCarousel',
        props: {          
            carouselUrl: String,
        },
        setup(props) {
            let state= reactive({songs:[]})
         

            onMounted(()=>{
             axios
                    .get(props.carouselUrl)
                    .then(response => {
                        state.songs = response.data.results[0].category_tracks
                        console.log(state.songs)
                    })
                
            })

            return {
                state,
            }
        },
</script>
```

Comment: Hey @boussadjra-brahim, thanks man! I've tried this approach before but it didn't work. I guess my mistake was making `song` an object and not an array, since `response.data.results[0].category_tracks` is supposed to be an iterable array right?

Comment: you're welcome, yes it should be an array and nested in the object passed to reactive, please don't forget to upvote my answer

Comment: Shouldn't it be `state.songs = response.data.results[0].category_tracks`?

Comment: What I also notice is that if I try to assign `songs` to another variable like `let songs = state.song` or return `{ songs: state.songs }`, then it will not render in template. Why is that? I'm sorry if my question sounds dumb, I'm somehow new to vue and its composition-api.

Comment: @yom-s, you're right. It should be `state.songs = response.data.results[0].category_tracks`

Comment: @AjayiOlamide you could use `toRef` like `return { songs: toRef(state,'songs') }`, don't forget to import it `import { reactive, onMounted,toRef } from 'vue'` then use `songs` without state in template